# Unity - Build Settings Window runs slow

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, lag

So this is a weird one. The window that loads when you open up the build setting in Unity (2019.4.10f1) seems to be lagging up my computer.

No other part of Unity does this and I haven’t found any help with it. Anyone got any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Usually when unity is like this it depends on nvidia drivers. But of course what you are describing is really vague and could be anything